# Wrap an HTML form with a specific ID in a new tag

Tags: html, forms, perl, replace

I have a Perl script that parses through HTML and modifies the content.  I’d like to update my script below to wrap a noindex tag around a specific ID on the page.

**Relevant Perl Info**

```
undef $/;
my $doc = <>;

if ($main::atomz_search_url=~ m{mydomain.com/(.+?)/support}si) 
{
$doc =~ s{<div id="header">}{<div id="header" class="noindex">}sig;
}
```

**Current HTML**

```
<form id="search" action="../results.html" method="post">
  <fieldset>
        ...
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I simply want to find the FORM with an ID of “search” and wrap the entire FORM block (including original content) with a noindex tag.

```
<noindex>
 <form id="search" action="../results.html" method="post">
  <fieldset>
        ...
  </fieldset>
 </form>
</noindex>
```

Note:  I can only use core modules so `Mojo` isn't an option.

Comment: http://shadow.cat/blog/matt-s-trout/mstpan-4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that this is one specific task a simple-minded text processing may do.
If you have more to do I recommend using a suitable package.

It is critical that html `form`s cannot be nested, so you can search for your pair of form tags.

If you can read the whole page into a string

```
my $file = 'page_with_form.html';
my $page = do {
    local $/ = undef; 
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!; 
    <$fh>;
};
$page =~ s{(<form\s+id="search".+?</form>)}{<noindex>\n$1</noindex>}s;
```

If the page is too large to read into a varialbe, read it line by line and use markers for (the lines with) the opening and closing tags for your form. Let me know if I need to add this.

Answer (score 2):

Put down the regex and get something designed for the purpose. Mojo::DOM for example.

```
use Mojo::DOM;
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($doc);
$dom->at("#search")->wrap("<noindex></noindex>");
say $dom;
```

Comment: I wish I could; unfortunately this is a SaaS tool from Adobe called Search & Promote of which we cannot add/modify their environment to use any other tools.  I'll need a solution in pure Perl

Comment: @user1754738 Mojo::DOM *is* pure Perl, but I'm guessing you mean you can only use core modules. You should edit that information into your question.